# Screen sizes and densities for Android

Tags: android, screen, dpi

I'm currently working on 2 Android projects and seems like I have a problem with understanding how to handle the density of resources. I have a HTC One M8, which has ~440 dpi, therefore I'm using XXHDPI. I always use XXHDPI resources and wrap content for the elements. On one of the projects, all the resources are png formats, again using XXHDPI and wrap content and when running the app, it looks great.
On the other hand, the resources from the other project are .9.pngs. Whenever I use XXHDPI and wrap content, in the preview, the design of the elements is altered, the pictures are really shrank.

However, if I use a HDPI, the size of the picture will look good, but the pixel's density will be crap. As far as I know, I should never hardcore the width and the height of the picture, but get the picture with the specific density and just use wrap content.

Am I missing something or there is a problem with the resources?

Comment: Did you scale the 9 patches?

Comment: @Funkystein - I don't scale them, doing so, it will just funk up the picture such as, if I have a picture with some text ("ABCD" for instance), changing the width to a smaller one will only show me A and D mostly, B and C will me somewhere in the middle, not readable at all

Comment: This looks like cropping, not scaling. I meant **resizing** (as a whole)

Comment: @Funkystein it's not actually cropping, the middle part of that element is still available, but it's messed up a bit, don't know how to describe it. I would say that should be the problem as well :-)

Comment: To scale a 9 patch properly, you have to first select **ALL BUT THE 1 px BORDER**. Resize **this portion only**. Then **recreate** the 1 px border and the black markers. Make sure the file ends with **.9.png**.

Comment: @Funkystein - thanks! But that would not be my problem, but the resources I received which will be handled by somebody else

Comment: Make sure that "somebody else" knows how to scale 9 patches depending on dpi, then.